# Prevent user-mode APCs from user mode

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

Kernel-mode code can [prevent some or all asynchronous procedure calls (APCs) by entering a *critical or guarded region* or by *Raising the current IRQL*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/disabling-apcs). That way, it is possible to execute code containing alertable waits without interference from APCs.

**Is there a similar way for user-mode code to (temporarily) disable user-mode APCs in the current thread?**

---

I'd be happy about answers for both managed and unmanaged code. I already verified that the following methods do *not* work:

- critical sections (`EnterCriticalSection`/`LeaveCriticalSection`)
- stdlib mutexes (`std::mutex`, `std::recursive_mutex`, ...)
- managed synchronization features (`lock` statements, `MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)` annotation)

Comment: Do you mean preventing a user-mode APC from running on the current thread, a particular other thread, any thread in the process (including ones that haven't yet been created), or all processes in the current login session?

Comment: (And note that all the things you said about kernel mode only prevents APCs from interrupting the current thread, they can still run on other threads)

Comment: User APCs run only when a thread enters an alertable state. So don't enter an alertable state.

Comment: @RaymondChen: That's good enough for native code, but possibly hard to achieve when a managed runtime is playing involuntary context-switching games with your thread (for example, .NET garbage collection, or `Thread.Abort`)  Those can in some sense be considered as user-mode asynchronous calls, even though they aren't OS APCs.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm only interested in guarding a short section of (managed) code running on a single thread. So yes, I'm searching for a method for the current thread only.

Comment: @RaymondChen Sadly I cannot prevent entering an alertable state (a blocking call to a WCF proxy towards a local process).

Comment: @dsf: Sure you can.... move the WCF call to another thread, and use a non-alertable wait to detect when the other thread makes progress.

Comment: @BenVoigt My (short) tests lead me to believe that moving all alertable waits to separate threads is non-trivial. If that's the only solution I'll take it, but a way to disable APCs would seem nicer to me. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: @dst: Well, disabling alertable wait is supposed to be trivial.  There's a `bAlertable` parameter on each WinAPI function that potentially enters alertable wait.  The difficulty is with libraries/frameworks that wait on your behalf, taking that level of control away from the programmer.

Comment: in user mode APC calls can be only if you call several special api (inside this calls). but if you call this api - no way prevent this (if you not hook `ntdll.KiUserApcDispatcher`). and why you think that APC is problem at all. you are yourself queue APC to thread ? or you afraid that some external code do this ?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? Why do you think that preventing APC's is part of the solution?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm writing a library loaded by a closed-source third party application (Outlook). I implement a mostly synchronous API (MAPI) that can be called from that application on any thread. This application registers user-mode APCs, which *also* call my library. In the implementation, I need to access a managed local process (using WCF, which forces alertable waits). Many of these calls are in non-reentrant critical sections. I now run into race conditions where an APC calls the method it interrupted, attempting to re-enter the critical section.

Comment: @dst - so your real problem not in apc but in recursive calls your api, which non-reentrant. however you can easy check are call is recursive

Comment: @IInspectable (2) I see three options: prevent APC calls from happening (this question), serializing WCF calls on some dedicated thread that has not APCs scheduled (which has some performance implications and just doesn't seem right to me) or refactoring the critical sections to rewind whenever a problematic APC happened (a real-world example: Outlook reads multiple rows of a table using a cursor, while the APC updates the same cursor. Don't ask me *why* Outlook scheduled that APC, that part is out of my control).

Comment: @RbMm yes, my 'real' problem is an APC calling a non-reentrant API, me implementing that API and not having any control over that APC. Checking if the call is re-entrant does not help me, as I still need to return a valid result to both the APC call and the 'normal' one.

Comment: @dst - why is your code non-reentrant ? the EnterCriticalSection is re-entrant. what make your code is such ?

Comment: anyway - no any api for disable user mode APC - if you call several api with `bAlertable==true` and exist APC inserted to thread - it will be called. the correct way in this case - change your code for make it re-entrant. also very interesting will be look for stack trace on re-entrant call for view who and what called and where you deadlock(?)

Comment: @RbMm the problem is that the logic is not re-entrant. In the example above: iterating over a table using a cursor pointing to the next row crashes if the cursor is set to null between the check for null and the actual access to the row. The codebase is not built with the assumption that every call to the local process can lead to re-entrancy (the problematic race conditions do not occur on the development machine, for reasons I don't yet understand).

Comment: @RbMm "no any api for disable user mode APC" -> that sounds like an answer to the question. Feel free to post it :)

Comment: you can before WCF calls save state and restore it after call for example

Comment: I'm not convinced, that this is a real issue. It starts to sound like you are violating COM rules and are now trying to find a fix for issues caused by those violations. I could be wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable do you refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810016.aspx ? If not: do you have a link or other reference to those 'COM rules' you suspect me to violate? Some of the rules in the linked document are bent by the MAPI interfaces themselves (especially regarding memory management), but I don't think these differences are related to my issues. Other than that, I don't see obvious violations to the rules; but I'm certainly no COM expert so it is possible that I missed something.

Comment: COM has specific rules pertaining to threading, the guarantees interface implementations need to provide, and how to access interfaces across apartment boundaries. [Processes, Threads, and Apartments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/processes--threads--and-apartments) has more information.

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't see anything in my code that violates these guidelines. All methods are safe to call from any thread in the same apartment. The problem only occurs if a new call to the same COM object starts on the same thread, before the original call finished. I did not find any COM rules regarding alertable waits or APC scheduling, though.
Maybe it helps if I put this question in another way: "Is it possible to execute code with alertable waits without executing scheduled user-mode APCs?" would be roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** The only options to prevent user-mode APCs from happening are:

- Not scheduling APCs in the first place
- Not performing alertable waits
- Scheduling the APCs on another thread
- Moving all alertable waits into another thread that has no APCs scheduled or does not permit alertable waits in the first place

  [`QueueUserWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ms684957(v=vs.85).aspx) seems like good candidate, when using `WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT`:

  > The callback function is queued to a thread that [...] cannot perform an alertable wait.

<sub>(Thanks to [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm) for assuring that there is no user-mode API to disable APCs in the comments)</sub>